# Does the MediaElement.js plugin preload content without hitting play?

Tags: mediaelement.js

At my website, http://simpleprogrammer.com, I've started including my latest podcast episode from Libsyn using a MediaElement.js plugin on Wordpress.

I've noticed that my download count for the podcast episode is pretty high, so I am wondering if somehow MediaElement.js is preloading the content before the user click play.  (I don't want to get false positives.)

I already fired up Fiddler to check for myself and it appears it only requests the content when play is clicked, but I wanted to double-check to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to know this and if it is possible to stop it from pre-loading. I have lots of players on the page and i don't want every single file to pre-load

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the value of the `preload` attribute on your `<audio>` element. Predictably, setting the `preload` attribute to `none` will prevent the audio from preloading (and in my experience, mediaelement.js doesn't override this behavior).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-preload

The spec includes other great attribute values, too, such as `metadata` which "indicates that only audio metadata (e.g. length) is fetched."